# IE8 blank filename on file upload

Tags: html, file-upload, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to upload an image to our server and it works on Chrome and Firefox and IE9 but not in IE8.  The filename in the request appears as blank for IE8 but not in Chrome.  The file retrieved by the server is 0 kilobytes (should be 219kb) in the case of IE8.

**HTML**

```
<form action="$!toolsServiceUrl" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="left-section" class="section right-border container">
    <input type="hidden" name="okRedirectURL" value="$!okRedirect" />
    <input type="hidden" name="errorRedirectURL" value="$!errorRedirect" />
    <input type="hidden" name="updateSection" value="LOGO_AND_MESSAGE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="loginGuid" value="$!loginGuid" />
    <input id="current-file" class="file hide" type="file" accept="image/*" name="file"/>
    <a id="upload-now" class="btn upload open-file">$!INTL_UploadNew</a>
    <input href="#" class="btn btn-primary submit-for-review" type="submit" value="$!INTL_SubmitForReview" />
</form>
```

**Chrome Request Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryhaQZT4Syn2OCktxQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="wallpaper-2055060.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

**IE8 Request Payload**

```
-----------------------------7dc230b1a0a3a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

(I omitted all the irrelevant data from the request payloads)

I need it to work on IE8 since a significant number of our users use IE8.

Comment: Are you accessing this from localhost, or are you connecting to your site remotely?

Comment: @Jaambageek The site is hosted on an internal network. The upload server is a different host on the same network, although in this case I was running the upload server locally for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you hide your file input field and then trigger click event using javascript to open file dialog. IE assumes that click as non secure and will not send to a server.

To avoid this you need click on real field OR make a `<label for="idOfFileInputField">` which is also will trigger "safe" click event.

Your code might look like:

```
<form action="$!toolsServiceUrl" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="left-section" class="section right-border container">
   ...
   <input id="current-file" class="file hide" type="file" accept="image/*" name="file"/>
   <label for="current-file" id="upload-now" class="btn upload open-file">$!INTL_UploadNew</label>
   ...
</form>
```

you should not also hide file input field with `display:none`, otherwise label click will not be triggered on it. Instead you make something like `position:absolute; left:-9999px` to hide from visible view-port.

Comment: IE8 has no problem letting you read the file input outside of a click/change event, but newer browsers won't let you access the filename or file data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the same thing from a remote machine, you might get a different result. There is a "security feature" (bug) in IE 8 regarding file uploads that causes them not to send the correct path of the file being uploaded. From what I understand this is only a problem when accessing the site locally though.

Check out this site for more info:
http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/the-mystery-of-cfakepath-unveiled/

It looks like from a remote machine you should be ok if you add the site to the trusted sites, in the browser preferences. But locally it still will not work.